# Django CMS - external redirection on new page

Tags: django, django-cms

Is it possible, without customizing the menu template, to have a menu item, which opens an external link on new page?

Comment: Can you show us some code or explain better?

Anyways do you want to open a link in another tab? Add **target = "_blank"**  in a tag

Comment: I can't, that's the point. Of course, I know I can do it using `target`, but I want a solution which can be easily configured on the admin interface. (Since it's desirable for non-coders to be able to edit the navigation)

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this or figure it out? I am looking for the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, not. One workaround is to hard-code the menu instead of letting the CMS generate it, that can be done quick by copy-pasting the generated code. Alternatively, you can create your own template tag and preferably extend the CMS functionality instead of hard-coding an exception for the menu item with the external redirect.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that ends up here looking for a solution to this. You can put the external link in the Redirect field in the Advanced settings for that Page[image]